# How to change a href when using multiple variables in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

So I didn't found what I was looking for in last two days.

To be clear I have a table "tracks" in my database.
So I can show from "tracks" the "demo" field which is an audio file "URL"..

```
 <?= $tracks['demo']; ?>
```

I have multiple URLs but then I need to replace the a href

```
<a href="<?php echo $tracks['demo'];?>"
```

in a logical way.

In simple terms it's like I want to click on button 1 that loads
URL 1 into this a href with the ID, title field from that track.

When you press button 2 you need to load another URL and replace URL 1 with url2.

I tried many ways including JavaScript but it won't work.

Problem now is that when I list 4 items it always loads the latest "URL" I have posted in my source code.

When I echo out `<?php echo $tracks['demo]; ?>` on all items I can see the correct URLs so the functionality to replace the URL is my issue.

*** I basically want to load many mp3 URLs in a player I made in the footer of my website. It works by hardcoding the URLs in the URL field but this is not what it should be... ***

Code:

```
<?php while($tracks = mysqli_fetch_assoc($muziek)) : ?>
   
   <div class="col-md-2 viny" id="muziek">
        <h4><?= $tracks['title']; ?></h4>
        <img src="<?= $tracks['img']; ?>" 
         alt=" <?= $tracks['title']; ?> />
        <p class="artist">Artist: <?= $tracks['artist']; ?></p>
    </div>
    <?= $tracks['demo'] = $audiourl ; ?>
    <button type="button" onclick="play">Play</button>

</div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

***THIS LOOPS PERFECTLY FOR ALL ITEMS TRACKS ARE LISTED PERFECTLY ***

In my player I have

```
<a href="<?php echo $audiourl;?>" ><?= $tracks['artist']; ?></b> - <?= $tracks['title']; ?></a> 

function play(){
```

I'm not good at JS... And this is my issue because it now loads the latest output from the PHP loop...
}

Comment: Please add your code. What you have tried ?

Comment: Please add html+javascript+php code what you tried so far.

Comment: @frederick are the url being loaded via ajax or server calls ??

Comment: Where is your for / foreach loop ?

Comment: need the complete code without that we cannot help. Sorry

Comment: man how are you implementing the replacing ??

Comment: The replacing is my issue. I have tried a lot and i cannot find the solution.

Comment: I can't see how you are replacing but I have posted a answer please review it

Comment: If you want the to fix your implemented replacing code then I need to see that particular code to see what is going wrong

Comment: @Gardezi I load it with server calls. I'm just nog good at JS functions. I want the best solution to replace the variable $audiourl when I click the button onclick="play()"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are replacing it but

Why not pass the audio in the function. Here like this

```
 <button type="button" onclick="play(<?= $tracks['demo'] = $audiourl ; ?>)">Play</button>
```

assign a id to anchor tag

```
<a id="someId" href="<?php echo $audiourl;?>" ><?= $tracks['artist']; ?></b> - <?= $tracks['title']; ?></a>
```

and in the play function, you receive it like this

```
function play(audioUrl){

}
```

and change the href like this in the play function

**If you are using jquery**

```
$('#someId').attr("href", audioUrl);
```

sometimes the above does not works. Can't remember why but if that does not works try this

```
$('#someId').href = audioUrl
```

**If you are using javascript**

```
document.getElementById('abcd').href = audioUrl
```

Comment: Hmm interesting. Did not tought about that. Will try ;) Thanks!

Comment: So far so good, in my debugger I see the correct url's loading in my function. So I'm almost there. Big Thanks.

Comment: you're welcome. If this helped you can you please accept it so that if any other  has this issue he or she can also get help :)

Answer (score 0):

So I tried many things but I had many issues with the player it's js file using the same id's and so on.

The new logic I tried out seems to work:

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
          <input type="submit" value="Play" name="Play">
          </form>


          <?php 

             if (isset($_POST["Play"]))
             {

              echo $tracks['demo'];
          }else{
            echo '&nbsp;';
          }
          ?>
```

There is more going on but I tried to write it down as simple as this to show the logic. All Track url's are hidden and when the page loads there is an empty $audiourl by default loaded in the a href from my audioplayer. By clicking the button play I show the url in the source but not on the site. 
Then the latest $audiourl variable changes to this value.